# Is it good practice to return False when expecting a non-bool return value?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a function that needs to return `n` random elements from a list, I may want to check if the number of elements in the list is larger than the sample I'm asking for, that is:

```
mysample = []

def rnd(n):
    if len(mysample) < n:
        return False
    return random.sample(mysample, n)
```

In this case I returned `False` if the number of elements asked for is larger than the number we have.

Is this good practice? The place where we're calling `rnd()` is expecting a list to be returned, not a boolean, so it doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: You'd better `raise` an exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's actually no need to do this, [`random.sample` does it for you (see end of its documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample):

> If the sample size is larger than the population size, a `ValueError` is raised.

In order to answer you question too, though, you'd usually want to raise an exception in these cases, not return something. If you don't, a user won't always realize an error has actually occurred (and an error should never pass silently).

Answer (score 1):

```
mysample = []

def rnd(n):
    if len(mysample) < n:
        return []
    return random.sample(mysample, n)
```

Just return an empty list, when you need to check, use:

```
if rnd():
    pass
```

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following
>   values are considered false:
>
> `None`
>
> `False`
>
> zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0.0`, `0j`.
>
> any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
>
> any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.

Comment: This doesn't allow the client to distinguish between a potentially valid call to `rnd` where `mysample` happens to be empty or `n` happens to be 0; and an invalid call perhaps due to a programming error which should raise an exception to flag the developer's attention.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding a little on Jim Fasarakis-Hilliard's answer ...

Returning special values in exceptional cases is error-prone, because any code calling your function then has to guard against the special case:

```
x = rnd(n)
if x == False:
    # deal with it
else:
    # do what you wanted to in the first place
```

Note that if `False` is your special value, you can't just say `if not x: ...` because that would catch an empty list, which is a valid return value in the "usual" case. Subtleties like this are common with special return values, and you can't assume that calling code will always anticipate them.

If the calling code neglects to guard against your special value, errors become harder to track down:

```
x = rnd(n)
#
# ... do some stuff ...
#
y = len(x)  # Aargh, TypeError ... where did that happen?
```

If you raise an exception instead:

```
def rnd(n):
    if len(mysample) < n:
        raise ValueError('n must be no larger than size of mysample')
    return random.sample(mysample, n)
```

... any error will happen where `rnd()` is called, with a helpful error message. If the exceptional case needs to be guarded against, the code to do so is more explicit (and less prone to subtle edge cases):

```
try:
    x = rnd(n)
except ValueError:
    # deal with it
# all is well, continue as normal
```